# How to make it as procedure?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have the scenario where a function returns an lambda form, and I want to apply the lambda form but failed. Example:

```
#lang racket

(define tes (lambda () `(lambda () 100)))
(tes)
((tes))
```

the result is:

```
'(lambda () 100)
. . procedure application: expected procedure, given: '(lambda () 100) (no arguments)
```

Then how can I make `(lambda () 100) as a procedure?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the backquote from the inner `lambda` expression, it will work. Alternately, you could immediately `unquote` after the backquote, but that amounts to a noop:

```
> (define tes (lambda () (lambda () 100)))
> ((tes))
100
> (define tes (lambda () `,(lambda () 100)))
> ((tes))
100
```

Comment: hmm..what if I can't change the source code? meaning it just returns `(lambda () 100), then how to change it to (lambda () 100)?

Comment: @freezdom similar to your question about strings and symbols, one answer is `eval`, but using `eval` is probably not the right choice. Perhaps you could post a question that explains the overall problem you're trying to solve; it would probably be more effective than getting answers in small pieces.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I find it a little hard to present the problem as a whole..... Basically, I am doing some transformation on a program, I need to change some terms, a stupid example, if the source code `(lambda (x y) 100)`, the transformation process uses `match`, then returns `(lambda (x y z) 100), which I need to make it executable again.

Comment: @freezdom you may want to consider using macros (http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/macros.html) rather than functions to implement this sort of transformation. Alternately, you can do the transformations to lists that represent programs, and then read the transformed program in later as a source file.

Comment: You are right. It seems that the right way is do `transformation into lists and then read the program in later as a source file`. I CAN NOT do the transformation to lists and make it runnable as program directly.

Comment: @freezdom: If you *really* want to manipulate and evaluate code *at run-time*, there is nothing wrong with using `eval`—that's what it's there for, after all.  In such a case, generating source code text files and loading those seems like a kluge.  On the other hand, run-time code generation is rarely necessary.  Compile-time code generation via macros is usually (but not always) more appropriate.

Comment: @Matthias is right; if you really do need to do run-time generation, `eval` is appropriate. However, it sounds like you're just implementing a code optimizer, where it would be more appropriate to do perform the optimization and then run the program in separate phases, much like a compiler.

Comment: @acfoltzer Well, actually the job I am doing is kind of in the middle, which I confused myself, obviously.